# Drawing circle with unique color near checkboxes

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have checkbox list which contains a lot of items. Also I have predefined array of different color's code: ['#FF0000', #DDFF00, ... ] (5 items). I need to provide the following ability: to check checkboxes and draw circle with unique color from color's array (max count of checked items = length of color's array). For example: if I checked 5 checkboxes - checking ability is blocked. If I uncheck any items I need to determine what color used for this items and use it for next checking.

Comment: Drawing circle is not problem. But it is not clear for me how I can make described manipulations with colors.

Comment: Now I use unlimited colors, which generates randomly and draw circles with Raphael.